# Merge Two Pandas Dataframes when two columns are list

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Pandas data frames and they need to be merged.  Example data frames are:

```
         c1  c2
pd1 = [[1, [1,2]]

         c3  c4
pd2 = [[1, [1,3]], 
       [2,[2,3]]

result = [[1,1], [1,2]]
```

The join condition is that lists in c2 and c4 have at lease one common element.

I've tried:

```
result = pd.merge(pd1, pd2, left_on=list('c2'),right_on=list('c4'), how='inner')
```

However, this seems to only join them when the rows in each column are single values like a float, int or string.

I've attacked this problem using nested loops.  This runs like a dog when the sets get large.  Is there a faster way to perform this merge exploiting data frames or is there another way that's better?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, [1,2]]], columns=['c1', 'c2'])
pd1
```

[image]

```
pd2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, [1, 2]], [2, [2, 3]]], columns=['c3', 'c4'])
pd2
```

[image]

#### Setup for a merge

```
s2 = pd2.c4.apply(pd.Series).stack() \
        .rename_axis(['idx2', 'lst2']).reset_index(name='val')
s2
```

[image]

```
s1 = pd1.c2.apply(pd.Series).stack() \
        .rename_axis(['idx1', 'lst1']).reset_index(name='val')
s1
```

[image]

```
mrg = s1.merge(s2)[['idx1', 'idx2']].drop_duplicates()
mrg
```

[image]

```
a1 = pd1.c1.loc[mrg.idx1].values
a2 = pd2.c3.loc[mrg.idx2]

pd.DataFrame(dict(c1=a1, c3=a2))
```

[image]